# how to fill up a dropdown with the data of a ordener list jquery

Tags: jquery

If I have the following list:

```
<ol class="list">
    <li id="1">one</li>
    <li id="2">two</li>
    <li id="3">three</li>
 </ol>
<select id="npip"></select>
```

And now I want to fill up a select with the text of each `<li>` of the list. I mean, the option and text of my select, should be options(1,2,3) with text (one, two, three). This was what I tryed, but I don't understand why is not working:

```
$("#npip").append($('.list').html());
$("#npip option").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple solution should do the job. http://jsfiddle.net/ycxowLm9/

```
$(".list li").each(function(key, value){
   $("#npip").append(new Option($(value).html(), $(value).prop("id"))); 
});
```